Traffic light circuit does not change the LEDs periodically
!! I'm a beginner with electronic circuits, sorry the question !!
I have this circuit on LiveWire, it has to change between the three LEDs periodically but i dont know if is the version of my LiveWire that is too old(1.1v) or the circuit is wrong.
On the Tinkercad side, the second circuit keeps giving me that error (supposedly, I should transcribe the LiveWire circuit).



what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

keeps giving me that error ... what error? ... please add a description to your post

They are a bit on the pricey side, but you could use Multi-Layer Ceramic Capacitors. These are not polarized and will not cause problems. In you simulation, just use a non-polarized capacitor (ceramic will do).

@jsotola Sorry, the error: Capacitor is inversely polarized with -1.22V when i run the simulation

@MarcoJ. please add the description to the question, not in a comment

The problem with your circuit is that you are using polarized capacitors, and the voltage across those capacitors alternates as the circuit cycles. The solution is to not use polarized capacitors. In simulation, use any non-polarized capacitor the simulator supports, such as ceramic. In real life, you could use Multi-Layer Ceramic Capacitors. They are a bit pricey, but for three of them, they won't break the bank. If you were making 1000s of these circuits, you would want to consider all alternatives available for reducing the price.
Also, you resistors are too small, which makes the LEDs on continuously. Here is a circuit that works. It uses 3 extra transistors and three extra resistors. I was not able to get a three-phase multivibrator to work with LEDs going directly from the collectors of the transistors to ground, so I added emitter followers and current limiting resistors. I'm not saying one cannot get the circuit you have to work, provided it has the right components. However, I wasn't able to get it to work in the time I was willing to spend on it.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The left most resistor is different from the others to ensure the oscillations start up in simulation. In reality, the resistors will not be equal anyway.
Here is the current through each LED.


Thank you, now they dont crash, but I want help with the topic of periodic blinking of each LED in loop, they just stay on

The resistors are too small. I will edit my answer with a schematic that works.
